# VF page for System Admin to list details of all apps in the organization

Tags: visualforce

is it possible to create a VF page visible to System Admin which will list and provide links for all the apps present in the organization?

please provide pointers on how to proceed with it

Comment: There is a list that sounds similar to what you want at: **Setup** > **Create** > **Apps**

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from Object **[AppMenuItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appmenuitem.htm)** . In which you will get complete details and you can use read-only object to view an entry in the Force.com App Menu. You can create a SOQL query to retrieve all items, even those a user does not see from the user interface.